# Buy IP range independent of provider

Tags: ip, bgp

I would like to ask a question.
Is there any wat to acquire IP, independent of provider?

Can I buy IPs and use them in different data centers? We have physical servers in the united states and germany. Is it possible to buy IPs and use them in datacenters?

I believe it is not possible, because of routing/BGP and so on.

Thank very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I buy IPs and use them in different data centers? We have physical servers in the united states and germany. Is it possible to buy IPs and use them in datacenters?

Technically, yes, definitely.  You can:

- get IP addresses the way ISPs get them, through direct membership in your region's Internet Registry (e.g. ARIN, RIPE, LACNIC); or
- get IP addresses through an assignment from an existing RIR member (e.g. some ISPs and/or datacenter operators might offer this service); or
- these days, for IPv4 – purchase someone else's address block in one of the "second-hand IPv4 markets".

In all cases you'll be able to get just the addresses, independently from a connection.

But in practice, IPv4 might cost you a lot, as there are simply no more addresses left to assign from the regional registries – only bought "used" from the IPv4 brokers. (IPv6, on the other hand, is fairly cheap and in some cases outright free.)

> I believe it is not possible, because of routing/BGP and so on.

BGP is exactly what *makes* it possible – however, you need to arrange its use with each datacenter's operators, so that you could announce your own IP ranges through BGP to the Internet.

Note that for IPv4, a `/24` (i.e. a block of 256 addresses) is the smallest announcement that most network operators will accept – a single IP address won't do – and getting a /24 will cost you quite a lot, these days.

(As mentioned, the Regional Registries have no more /24's to hand out to members, so you'll usually need to get one from a "used IPv4" broker. As of today [2023-12], the market price seems to be about $9,000–$12,000 for a single /24 block.)

This means that even if you do manage to get this done, you might need to share *one* /24 across all your datacenters, which would require ordering some sort of L2VPN service (or setting up GRE tunnels) to relay packets from one datacenter to others (site A receives all packets, some of them go to local servers at A, others are tunneled to sites B and C).

On the other hand, for IPv6, the smallest range is a `/48`, and that's very easy to obtain, even for individuals. (RIR membership gives you a /32 to begin with.)

Comment: Stupid question, but what ensures unique use of the IPs? Why can't people just cheat and use IPs that they haven't bought?

Comment: @samlaf: Their upstream providers will usually have filters on what BGP announcements they'll accept from customers, often built from the same Internet Registry databases (e.g. from RIPE's ROA data). Occassionally it does happen that there are no filters and it's actually somewhat common for spammers to announce prefixes that nobody owns, and it's [happened a few times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGP_hijacking#Public_incidents) that ISPs themselves "mistakenly" announced someone else's prefixes, but _mostly_ it's caught by the announcement filtering.

Comment: @samlaf: So if the person cannot do the BGP prefix announcement due to filters (or if they rely on their upstream provider to do BGP announcements on their behalf, and that provider knows and refuses to announce IPs that don't belong to the customer), then there's nothing that would route towards them all the packets that would be sent "to" those IPs. Meaning, the person can send a fake packet but will never be able to receive a response; the response will go to wherever the _real_ owner is (or nowhere at all). Which is useful for DDoS attacks but pretty much useless in all other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Provided that the subnet length is <24, data centres will quite happily  allow you to use your own. How you connect to them is another question, and will either require you to supply router function, or have the dc do that for you.

The reason for the minimum subnet length being 24, is to try and keep the routing tables small.